# How to indicate nodata into gdal_calc formula

Tags: nodata, gdal-calc

I have a recurrent problem with `gdal_calc`.

Say I have two rasters I need to sum together, in which the same nodatavalue is set (e.g. `--NoDataValue = 0`).

In order to account for the fact that nodata + data = nodata, my formula would ideally look like this:

```
--calc="where(A==nodatavalue,0,A)+where(B==nodatavalue,0,B)"
```

Unfortunately, the "real" nodatavalue (i.e. zero) is not recognized (so anything like `--calc="where(A==0)...` would NOT work), nor I find any other way to refer to it.

Any ideas that DO NOT include the prior use of `gdal_edit -unsetnodata`?

Comment: What happens if you replace `nodatavalue` with `0/0`?

Comment: If you mean:
--calc="where(A==0/0,0,A)+where(B==0/0,0,B)"

the result is 
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Comment: Yes, assuming that the expression proposed by you works using another value for `A` and `B`.

Comment: Thanks mgri for your reply, but actually, as I wrote, using 0/0 as nodatavalue in the formula results in an obvious error, so my question is still open.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach (without altering your input data with `gdal_edit`) could be using GDAL VRT files as intermediate operands in `gdal_calc` and `-a_nodata none` in `gdal_translate` to skip the NoData values. For instance, if the original NoData value = 0:

```
gdal_translate -of VRT raster1.tif raster1.vrt -a_nodata none
gdal_translate -of VRT raster2.tif raster2.vrt -a_nodata none
gdal_calc.py -A raster1.vrt -B raster2.vrt --calc="A+B" --outfile=result.tif
```

In other cases, your calc expression should be applied to filter the NoData value and set it to 0.

Comment: This works, but it takes my processing time from 3 seconds up to 76 seconds on a grid with about 30M cells, much of which is NoData.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with GDAL version 3.3, a new [hideNoData option](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html#cmdoption-hideNoData) has been added to gdal_calc to enable nodata values to be considered in your calc formulas, thus eliminating the need to do other preprocessing steps. I haven't been able to test this yet, but it looks promising!

Comment: It is not working yet in gdal 3.4.0. Very new and buggy by now.

Comment: Thanks @nadya for the update. Are there any reported bugs/issues on the GDAL Github? https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues

Answer (score 0):

`--calc="(A>=0)*(A)+(B>=0)*(B)+logical_and(A>=0,B>=0)*(A+B)"`

But for some reason when A and B aren't null, the set (A+B)*2 ...