# comparison operators with Process Modeler's Raster Calculator

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I am trying to process some raster imagery using QGIS 2.18.7 on OS X 10.10.5.
I want to use a comparison operator (<, >, etc...) within the raster calculator in the process modeler (the one located under GDAL[Miscellaneous], not the SAGA one).

I can successfully get the calculator to perform an arithmetic operator by entering "A+1" in the "Calculation in gdalnumeric syntax using +-/* or any numpy array functions (i.e. logical_and())" field (quotes mine). Like I said, this works but produces an error/warning I don't understand.

> Algorithm Recoding1Month starting... Prepare algorithm:
>   GDALOGRRASTERCALCULATOR_1 Running Raster calculator 1 [1/1]
>   Parameters: INPUT_A
>   =/QGISWork/MODFireBurned/Tiffs/2001/y2001NicaBurnedUTM.tif, BAND_A =1, INPUT_B =None, BAND_B =1, INPUT_C =None, BAND_C =1, INPUT_D =None,
>   BAND_D =1, INPUT_E =None, BAND_E =1, INPUT_F =None, BAND_F =1, FORMULA
>   =(A+1), NO_DATA =, RTYPE =1, EXTRA = GDAL command: gdal_calc.py --calc "(A+1)" --format GTiff --type Int16 -A
>   /QGISWork/MODFireBurned/Tiffs/2001/y2001NicaBurnedUTM.tif --A_band 1
>   --outfile /var/folders/8y/6924gdvx3jg6k2rz5yrzwz100000gr/T/processing1524180f5e1443d3a74b4fdc0a8bd484/27a58e4ed8ce4200bb71345c1a315e52/OUTPUTALGGDALOGRRASTERCALCULATOR1.tif
>   GDAL command output:
>   /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/Programs/gdal_calc.py:272:
>   FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise
>   object comparison in the future.  myNDVs=1*numpy.logical_or(myNDVs==1,
>   myval==myNDV[i])  0 .. 10 .. 20 .. 30 .. 40 .. 50 .. 60 .. 70 .. 80 ..
>   90 .. 100 - Done  Converting outputs OK. Execution took 0.352 ms (1
>   outputs). Model processed ok. Executed 1 algorithms total Converting
>   outputs Loading resulting layers Algorithm Recoding1Month finished

More importantly, I cannot seem to get a comparison operator to produce the expected boolean (1 or 0) output when I enter "(A < 1)".  In fact this crashes and fails to produce any output file. This yields the following log message:

> Algorithm Recoding1Month starting... Prepare algorithm:
>   GDALOGRRASTERCALCULATOR_1 Running   [1/1] Parameters: INPUT_A
>   =/QGISWork/MODFireBurned/Tiffs/2001/y2001NicaBurnedUTM.tif, BAND_A =1, INPUT_B =None, BAND_B =1, INPUT_C =None, BAND_C =1, INPUT_D =None,
>   BAND_D =1, INPUT_E =None, BAND_E =1, INPUT_F =None, BAND_F =1, FORMULA
>   =(A=, RTYPE =1, EXTRA = GDAL command: gdal_calc.py --calc "(A GDAL command output:
>   /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/Programs/gdal_calc.py:272:
>   FutureWarning: comparison to `None` will result in an elementwise
>   object comparison in the future.  myNDVs=1*numpy.logical_or(myNDVs==1,
>   myval==myNDV[i])  0 .. 10 .. 20 .. 30 .. 40 .. 50 .. 60 .. 70 .. 80 ..
>   90 .. 100 - Done  Converting outputs OK. Execution took 0.381 ms (1
>   outputs). Model processed ok. Executed 1 algorithms total Converting
>   outputs Loading resulting layers Algorithm Recoding1Month finished

Note that, within these output logs, the command seems to be interpreted the way I'd expect for the arithmetic operator "**EXTRA = GDAL command: gdal_calc.py --calc "(A+1)"**"  but is messed up for the comparison operator: "**EXTRA = GDAL command: gdal_calc.py --calc "(A** " (my external quotes).  So clearly I'm making some sort of error but I cannot find helpful examples of how to format for "gdalnumeric syntax"  (a Google search for this yields only 115 results) or for "numpy array functions" within the raster calculator.  I found this more complex example which seems to suggest the comparison operators are possible: [gdal_calc raster calculator syntax for logical operators and other functions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204387/gdal-calc-raster-calculator-syntax-for-logical-operators-and-other-functions). In fact, this (http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html) seems to suggest that (A<1) should be allowed within the numpy syntax.  I have tried adding quotes, but it still doesn't work. So, I'm very confused.

How can I use comparison operators with the process modeler raster calculator?