# gdal calc to convert multiple values

Tags: gdal, gdal-calc

I'm trying to use GDAL calc to convert values in a .tif file, I've done this before with GDAL calc but for converting to a single value. Now I'm trying to convert multiple values in this fashion:

0.0 - 0.2 -> 1

0.2 - 0.4 -> 2

0.4 - 0.6 -> 3

etc

I've tried this:

```
    calculation='((0.0<A<0.2)*1)+((0.2<A<0.4)*2)+((0.4<A<0.6)*3)+
    ((0.6<A<0.8)*4)+((0.8<A<1.0)*5)+((1.0<A<1.5)*6)+((1.5<A<2.0)*7)+
    ((2.0<A<2.5)*8)+((2.5<A<3.0)*9)+((3.0<A<9999)*10)'

    call([sys.executable, 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py', '-A', 
    inraster, "--outfile=" + outraster, '--calc='+calculation,'--
    NoDataValue=-9999','--overwrite'])
```

This results in the following error:

```
    0 .. evaluation of calculation [thecalculation] failed
```

Any ideas? Maybe I need to split up the steps of converting but this could add significantly to the run time.

Comment: have you tried (0<A)*(A<=0.2)*1 + ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is chaining operators with an array. Python can handle `a<b<c` but only if `a`, `b` and `c` are scalars. In this case `b` is an array. For more: see [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html) and a  [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355495/why-doesnt-chained-interval-comparison-work-on-numpy-arrays).

Assuming that is the problem, then based on [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204387/gdal-calc-raster-calculator-syntax-for-logical-operators-and-other-functions) I imagine you can use something like this:

```
calculation='(logical_and(0.0<A,A<=0.2)*1)+(logical_and(0.2<A,A<=0.4)*2)+(logical_and(0.4<A,A<=0.6)*3)+(logical_and(0.6<A,A<=0.8)*4)+(logical_and(0.8<A,A<=1.0)*5)+(logical_and(1.0<A,A<=1.5)*6)+(logical_and(1.5<A,A<=2.0)*7)+(logical_and(2.0<A,A<=2.5)*8)+(logical_and(2.5<A,A<=3.0)*9)+(logical_and(3.0<A,A<=9999)*10)'
```

Failing that there is a useful tool called [gdal_reclassify](https://github.com/chiatt/gdal_reclassify) that is straight forward to use and has clear docs. Your use case would require something like this (NB only done for 4 classes):

```
python gdal_reclassify.py source_dataset.tif destination_dataset.tif -c "<0.2, <0.4, <0.6, <0.8" -r "1, 2, 3, 4" -d 0 -n true -p "COMPRESS=LZW"
```

You could build this call into your script as well.

If you're already working in a python script you could also just read to  numpy array, and use numpy directly to do the reclassification.

Comment: gdal_reclassify worked a charm! Fantastic answer, thank you so much!

Comment: And for the record, the method with logical_and's did not work, it threw an error.

Comment: Think that was my fault with the brackets. Might work now, not that it's needed!