# What is the correct GDAL Calc Syntax?

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, gdal-calc

I need to calculate in gdal_calc the following python script.

```
if (A == 0 and B == 0):
        wd = 0.0
    else:
        wd = np.arctan2(A,B)
```

I have tried

```
if(A = 0 && B = 0,(0.0), else,(arctan2(A,B)))
```

But the result isn't correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nupmpy's `arctan2` [function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html) already returns `0.0` when `A==0` and `B==0` so you don't need your if/else statement. Additionally, this function takes positional arguments of the form `arctan2(y,x)` so be sure to check this aligns with your intended calculation.

Based on your specified parameters, try `--calc="arctan2(A,B)"`. If you can update your question with your actual `gdal_calc` command it will help with any further troubleshooting.

For more information on syntax see the `gdal_calc` [documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html#cmdoption-calc) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/205942/50240) answer to a similar question.

Comment: Thanks, the returned values are between ]-180,180] but I need then between  [0,360[.  For this the expression could be like -- calc="A+2pi(less(A,0))"?

Comment: Finally I've figured it out. The expression is (A+360)*(A<0). I only need now is to combine the two. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax formula for what I intended to do is:

```
((degrees (arctan2 (A,B)))+360)*((degrees (arctan2 (A,B)))<0)+(degrees (arctan2 (A,B)))*((degrees (arctan2 (A,B)))>=0)
```

This formula returns the wind direction in degrees [0, 360[ from U and V wind components.