# Raster calculator: using coefficients stored in csv table

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I need to calculate an expression over 25 different rasters. The function is the same for all rasters, but the coefficients are raster-specific. I would like to tell PyQGIS to select the relevant coefficients and then feed them into GDAL raster calculator formula.
To be more specific, I have rasters named as nl_y, where y is a numeric identifier, and coefficients relative to each y stored in a table (my_file_csv).

What I have tried to do - following Houska's advise - is to: (i) import the csv table as a layer without geometry; (ii) create a string reporting the expression to be applied in the raster calculator; (iii) feed this string into GDAL raster calculator.
Below is the code doing this:

```
## (i) Import csv with coefficients
uri = "file:///my_file_csv?delimiter=,"   
L_coeff = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "csvLayer", "delimitedtext")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(L_coeff)

for y in year:
    ## (ii) Select coefficients and compute formula
    for f in L_coeff.getFeatures():   
        if f["Var name"] == "Var 0":
            c0_y = f["Column " + y]
        if f["Var name"] == "Var 1":
            c1_y = f["Column " + y]
        if f["Var name"] == "Var 2":
            c2_y = f["Column " + y]

    formula_y = "(" + str(c0_y) + ")* (A > 0) + (" + str(c1_y) + ")* A + (" + str(c2_y) + ")* (A)^2"

    ## (iii) Raster calculation
    Fname_y = "nl_" + y + ".tif"
    processing.run("gdal:rastercalculator", {
        "INPUT_A": input_dir + "\\" + Fname_y,
        "BAND_A": 1,
        "FORMULA": formula_y,
        "OUTPUT": output_dir + "\\" + Fname_y})
```

I get output rasters but they have no-sense values - i.e. between 1.79769e+308 and -1.79769e+308, instead of having 0-63 range. My guess is that GDAL raster calculator does not correctly read the formula, even though when I print it, it is exactly identical to what I would write manually in GDAL algorithm.

Any idea on how I can apply raster calculation (not necessarily on GDAL!) in an automated manner using Python console in QGIS?

Comment: (Thinking out loud) Could you load your csv into your project as a Delimited text layer with no geometry, and then access it natively without pandas? You would then build your `"FORMULA"` parameter in your python code, referencing the proper "feature" in the csv layer to pull the coefficient values?

Comment: Great idea, I've tried it but I can't still get the desired result. I've update the question with the new code that I've attempted

Comment: Hmm. I'm not that experienced with applying the gdal calculator specifically. Ideas a) get it to debug-output `formula_y` to really check it's what you would use manually (you may have already done that), b) make sure your `NO_DATA` values are right (if applicable), c) give up on GDAL raster calculator and do a `numpy` calculation directly, see for instance https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204387/gdal-calc-raster-calculator-syntax-for-logical-operators-and-other-functions in another context.

Comment: You could use a model for that.

Comment: Can you expand on this? What do you mean with model?